# What does segofs mean?

Tags: c, memory, byte

I'm working on a C code in a embedded environnement and i would like to understand this :

```
#define linear2segofs(addr) (((((unsigned long) (addr)) & x00FFFF00UL) << 8) +\
                               (((unsigned long) (addr)) & 0x000000FFUL))
```

When I try it mathematically and it seem to move up bytes to upper parts of 32bit value.

I would like to understand why and what is a segofs.

Comment: **seg**ment **of**fset if I had to take a wild guess.

Comment: please provide how the macro is used. it seems to be doing a selective bitshifting, but we cannot guess if you don't tell which architecture or how it's used.

Comment: Reminds me of segment, offset, DOS days :)

Comment: What are the CPU and the SO? ... I think that is the macro to evalutate the memory segment of an address in a Intel CPU real mode environment!

Comment: just a **raw guess** ... in embedded environments usually you have to align manually the data you put in memory.  So the macro  probably converts the linear memory address to the segments the phisical memory has thus the shifts and selections. As I said, it's a guess

Answer (score 0):

This macro split linear address into segment and offset components. More info see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_segmentation).